# Using Spark with LSTM

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, deep-learning, lstm

I am still lost on the Spark and Deep Learning model.

If I have a (2D) time series that I want to use for e.g. an LSTM model. Then I first convert it to a 3D array and then pass it to the model. This is normally done in memory with numpy.

**But what happens when I manage my BIG file with Spark?**

The solutions I've seen so far all do it by working with Spark and then converting the 3D data in numpy at the end. At that solution puts everything in memory.... or am I thinking wrong?

*A common Spark LSTM solution is looks like this:*

```
# create fake dataset
import random 
from keras import models
from keras import layers
 
 
 
data = []
for node in range(0,100):
    for day in range(0,100):
        data.append([str(node),
                     day,
                     random.randrange(15, 25, 1),
                     random.randrange(50, 100, 1),
                     random.randrange(1000, 1045, 1)])
        
df = spark.createDataFrame(data,['Node', 'day','Temp','hum','press'])
 
# transform the data
df_trans  = df.groupBy('day').pivot('Node').sum()
df_trans = df_trans.orderBy(['day'], ascending=True)
 
#make train/test data
trainDF = df_trans[df_trans.day < 70]
testDF = df_trans[df_trans.day > 70]
 
 
################## we lost the SPARK #############################
# create train/test array
trainArray = np.array(trainDF.select(trainDF.columns).collect())
testArray = np.array(testDF.select(trainDF.columns).collect())
 
# drop the target columns
xtrain = trainArray[:, 0:-1]
xtest = testArray[:, 0:-1]
# take the target column
ytrain = trainArray[:, -1:]
ytest = testArray[:, -1:]
 
# reshape 2D to 3D
xtrain = xtrain.reshape((xtrain.shape[0], 1, xtrain.shape[1]))
xtest = xtest.reshape((xtest.shape[0], 1, xtest.shape[1]))
 
# build the model
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.LSTM(1, input_shape=(1,400)))
model.add(layers.Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
 
 
# train the model
loss = model.fit(xtrain, ytrain, batch_size=10, epochs=100)
```

**My problem with this is:**

If my Spark data uses millions of rows and thousands of columns, then when the **# create train/test array** program line tries to transform the data, it causes a memory overflow. Am I right?

**My question is:**

Can SPARK be used to train LSTM models on big data, or is it not possible?

Is there any Generator function that can solve this? Like the Keras Generator function?

Comment: ideally speaking it would be difficult to build a generator function (based on spark df). The reason behind that sparkdf are distributed over multiple nodes, and when you build a batch for (inside the generator function), you will have to do a `collect` kind of operation to bring all the data from distributed nodes and then make that available over the RAM and then push that to GPU memory for forward pass, loss calculation, and backprop. While this may just work for you (i am not sure if it will, because `tf.function` decorator are notorious when you use other libraries)

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you have too many columns in your dataframe - why would you have hundreds of columns?  Are you collecting that many data points for each timestamp?  If so, then I would argue that you need to subset your data.  In my experience, a time-series is driven largely by the timestamp - even a small number of data points stretched across a long collection of time provides enormous information.  In other words, you have a dataset that is wide and tall, but it should perhaps be thin and tall instead.

Comment: This is presumptuous, there many time-series problems where just chronological features (univariate time-series modeling) provide best results, and you need more exogeneous variables for better prediction.